# Angular js simple form validation not working on bootstrap model

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I've refereed so many questions but nothing helped me

Trying to create a form validation using official angular js doc

```
<div class="modal fade" ng-controller="LoginController" id="login" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<form name="form" method="POST" ng-submit="login(user)" novalidate>

<div class="md-form form-sm">
                <i class="fa fa-user prefix"></i>
                <input type="text" ng-model="user.email" name="email" class="form-control">
                <label for="form2">Email</label>
                <div ng-show="form.$submitted || form.email.$touched">
                  <div ng-show="form.email.$error.required">Email required.</div>
                </div>
              </div>
</form>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('LoginController',['$scope',function ($scope) {
    console.log('controller loaded');
})
```

But it doesn't worked

Comment: Nothing there in the plunker please update it

Comment: _But it doesn't worked_ what doesn't work? I'm going to guess if submits even if there are errors, to fix that change your `ng-submit` to `ng-submit(form.$valid && login(user))`

Comment: when click on submit button with empty textfield validation error is not shown

Comment: You don't have a `required` attribute on your email input element so there is no validation on if it's empty or not. P.S. have a look at [`ng-messages`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMessages/directive/ngMessages) makes it easier to write validation messages.

Comment: got it its the problem with `required` attribute